# focus when scrolling into view javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, getboundingclientrect

so long story short i have a 4 section page and im trying to make the border change on each section when the user scrolls by it. like if the user scrolls onto section one the border become yellow if he scrolls past it it goes back to normal
[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K1JR.png)

i made this function but the only issue is that it only works when i press the nav buttons other and i must activate all 4 buttons on the nav for it to work any help?

````
function myFunction(secNum) {
  const element = document.getElementById(`section${secNum}`);
  element.scrollIntoView({  behavior: 'smooth'});
  window.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
    let topPosition=element.getBoundingClientRect().top
    if(secNum==4){
      result=topPosition-177
    }else(result=topPosition)
    if(result>=0&&result<=250){
      element.style=`border-color:yellow;
      border-top-right-radius: 8px;
      border-top-left-radius: 8px;` 
    }
    else(
      element.style="border-color:black"
    )
  })
 }```
````

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the fiddle check out: <>
> you can use intersection observer
> for more info : https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=intersection+observer
> open code in another tab

```js
const allSection = document.querySelectorAll(".section");

const io = new IntersectionObserver(entries=>{
    entries.forEach(entry=>{
        if(entry.isIntersecting){
            entry.target.classList.add("yellow-border")
        }else{
            entry.target.classList.remove("yellow-border");
        }
    })
},{threshold:1});

allSection.forEach(section=>{
    io.observe(section);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="./p1.js" defer></script>
</head>
<style>
    .border{
        border: 2px solid black;
    }
    .yellow-border{
        border: 4px solid yellow;
    }
    .section{
        height: 30vh;
        padding: 4rem;
        margin: 4rem;
        transition: all 0.2s;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="border section section-1">section-1</div>
        <div class="border section section-2">section-2</div>
        <div class="border section section-3">section-3</div>
        <div class="border section section-4">section-4</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7rpntbak/21/